# Error while reading large file using ff package

Tags: r, csv, ff

I am trying to read a large file (1.51 GB) using the "ff" package. The following command was used:

```
atmins = read.csv.ffdf(file="atmins.csv", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE,
                       first.rows=10000, next.rows=50000, colClasses=NA)
```

However, after some time, I get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("recodeLevels") :    no applicable method for
>   'recodeLevels' applied to an object of class "logical"

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

use fread from data.table package